# Two possible meanings: identify how the sentence is meant

Tags: subject, ambiguity

Aus einem Kinderlied:
"Die Gans hat sieben Küken und jedes hat sie lieb."
The second part of the sentence could be read in two ways:

1. Die Gans hat jedes Küken lieb.
2. Jedes Küken hat die Gans lieb.

How to identify what is the intended/correct meaning? Are both correct and possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to infer the intended meaning from the sentence alone. Both interpretations are possible. Since it is a song, there's no prevalent word order either for each meaning because it depends on the meter.

The only way to get clarity is the **context**. In this case, I would say that interpretation (1) fits best since the verses seem to be introducing the duck and her relation to her family. I see no clue that the perspective changes to the chicken.